# How to find old (especially Soviet/Russian) blueprints

Tags: aerospace-engineering, technical-drawing, engineering-history

I am interested in old blueprints, especially if related to aerospace (and from the old Soviet Bloc), things like these: [Vostok blueprints](https://drawingdatabase.com/vostok-rocket/) [Soyuz blueprint](https://drawingdatabase.com/soyuz-rocket/).

Does anybody know if there is any methods to find them, if they are public domain/publicly available etc.?

They look like "official" documents, or at least made by someone in the field, as they are technical drawings with all of the trimmings.

Also, are there in general online repositories of old blueprints that can be publicly accessed?

Comment: Who do you expect to find them then scan them?

Comment: I'll start with contacting the professional/engineering society of that regard.

Comment: @Solar Mike No, I was in fact asking if there is an archive that could be contacted (I don't know, like a public library but for blueprints, "hey can I have a look at these documents") or even better an online archive of digitalized documents.

Comment: @r13 for example what societies could be contacted?

Comment: For my profession in the US, I'll check with ASCE, ACI, AISC, SDI...for old records, depending on the nature of the specific interest. For your case, you actually have much broader sources to check into, like societies in Russia, old Russian allies in Eastern Eurpe, and even NATO countries that have vast interests in Russian studies.

Comment: It might be better to ask this question at SE Space Exploration. It deals with rockets, satellites, space probes and rovers etc.

Comment: In duckduckgo.com I typed,        old soyuz blueprints,       and found quite a few.